# Counting set values in std::vector<bool>

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, boolean

Does `std::vector<bool>` use `POPCNT` instruction to compute the result of `std::count` algorithm?

If no, is it possible to implement without copy-pasting the complete vector? To do that, I need to access `unsigned int` values actually stored in that vector, is it possible?

If it matters, I only need VC++ 2017 solution.

Comment: You could easily check the generated assembly to see what it does.  Have you tried that?

Comment: @NathanOliver Just checked. Just as I expected, it doesn't. Is there an easy way to make it so?

Comment: @NathanOliver Bitwise shifts in the loop are slower that POPCNT by an order of magnitude: POPCNT will take 1 cycle to process 32 bool values.

Comment: I'm not sure of a way to do this with a vector since you don't have any direct access or any layout guarantees.  That said, `boost::dynamic_bitset` has a [count](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#count) function that could be optmized to make use of `POPCNT`

Comment: If you know that number of bits at compile time you could also use a `std::bitset` which also has a count function that could leverage `POPCNT`

Comment: @NathanOliver I don’t, depends on input data. Usually around 10 kbits, can be up to 1 MBit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::count` doesn't use `popcnt` for `std::vector<bool>` unfortunately (at least with GNU C++ standard library).

`std::vector<bool>` doesn't provide access to its raw storage either, `std::vector<bool>::data` returns `void`.

An alternative solution is to use `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`. `boost::dynamic_bitset<>::count` uses `popcnt` instruction, see [assembly output](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/mSOFWC).

GNU C++ `std::vector<bool>` is implemented sub-optimally and its size is 40 bytes. Whereas the `sizeof(boost::dynamic_bitset<>)` is 32.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but thanks for the quick response. I don’t like boost, I think I’ll just wrap `std::vector<uint64_t>`..

Comment: @Soonts Makes sense, and `sizeof(std::vector<uint64_t>)` is 24, even better than that of `boost::dynamic_bitset<>`. Unless you need `boost::dynamic_bitset<>` constructors from strings of bits.

Comment: I would stress that it is more important to properly configure compiler then use specific template solution.

Comment: @MarekR Compilers aren’t smart enough to emit fast code on their own, no matter how you configure them. The only way to get optimal performance is fall back to lower levels, `__popcnt64` intrinsic in my case.

Comment: Yes and no. First off all you have to configure compiler in such way that `popcnt` could be used. Secondly compiler can do amazing stuff, see: [cppcon where Matt Godbolt presents compiler explorer](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4?t=2514) (there is example for `popcnt`).

Comment: @MarekR Such optimizer tricks are unreliable. Even with `/arch:AVX2`, VC++ compiled that code into `BLSR` in a loop.

Comment: @Soonts you have missed my point. My point was that you have to properly configure your compiler so it could use some instruction. Now your requirement that compiler uses `popcnt` is strange. I read somewhere that  `popcnt` is peaty slow and alternative implementation with multiple instructions can be faster (cant provide source of that). Proper approach to such topics is create performance tests and do measurements and not read assembly if some instruction is used.

Comment: @MarekR `popcnt` has 1 cycle latency on Intel and AMD CPUs, see https://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf Please stop making vague non-specific claims.